# How to add column names to pipe delimited file of specific format

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dictionary

I have a file that contains user data

```
NS|Mrs|Jane|0001|07061980|random co|AS|001|4034|2/342 PT MMMMMY
```

I could do this to write colnames , but -

```
colnames = [name,code,DOB... ]
colnames = [i+'|' for i in colnames]
# then write this header to same txt file
```

But the problem is in the file is that user segments can occur at random.
The file has a specific format like -

- occurence of `NS` at the start denotes that all columns after `NS`, fall under name segment category. Name segments could be like name,code,DOB,company etc.
- Occurence of `AS` denotes that all columns after `AS`, fall under address segment. Like house number,pincode, address etc.
- segments can occur at random, some users might have `AS` listed first, other might have `NS` listed first

```
NS = [ 'title','name','code','DOB','company']
AS = [ 'state_code',house_num','pincode','address']
```

Need Output as a dataframe-

```
Title|Name|code|DOB|company|state_code|house_num|pincode|address
Mrs  |Jane|0001|07061980|random co|001|4034|2/342 PT MMMMMY
Mr   |John|0001|03061940|random co2|002|4034|2/342 AD MMMTM
```

Can anyone help ? I can provide more info if needed

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a clean data file.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f_in:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        #declare output order
        f_out.write('Title|Name|code|DOB|company|state_code|house_num|pincode|address\n')
        for line in f_in.readlines():
            if line.startswith('NS'): #correct order, just remove tags
                f_out.write(line.replace('NS|', '').replace('AS|', ''))
            elif line.startswith('AS'): #inverse order, change order
                peices = line.replace('AS|', '').replace('\n', '').split('|NS|')
                f_out.write(peices[1]+'|'+peices[0]+'\n')
```

Then read the file into a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('output.txt', sep='|')
```